# Git Extensions Authentication Error

Tags: authentication, ssh, putty, ssh-keys, git-extensions

I just downloaded git extensions. It is configured to use putty that comes with the installation. I used putty to create a private and public key and I have the agent started and I have added the private key.

I am using bitbucket and I have loaded my public key to my bitbucket account.

I get the ssh clone link from bitbucket and go to clone it in git extensions, I load the SSH key and hit clone and I get this error message.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1kJe.png)

I have an SSH key loaded. Why is it saying I need to load a key? I uninstalled gitextensions and generated different keys. I looked at all the settings, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

[Git Extensions SSH settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA9Vl.png)

Windows 10

Putty 0.70

Git extensions 2.51.01

bitbucket.org

Comment: Is this still relevant for you? I could assist, I remember it's a not-so-straightforward question )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

When you copy past the git command from bitbucket, it is the wrong syntax for git Extensions.

You will copy something like this:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:guitardenver/led-pad-pcb.git
```

But you need to remove the "git clone" part for it to work with git Extensions.

```
git@bitbucket.org:guitardenver/led-pad-pcb.git
```